# Django 3 в чем проблема шаблонизации?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Структура папок такая:
Папка templates  в ней 2 файла index.html(основной элемент вывода) и base.html(для шаблона)

Файл base.html

```
 {% extend "index.html" %}
    {% block style %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles_articles_tpl.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/highslide.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/calendar.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/seo.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fast.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/patch.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/slick.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/slick-theme.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}"/>
    {% endblock %}
```

Файл index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    {% block style %}{% endblock style %}
```

В файл index.html не добавляется содержимое блока style находящегося в base.html

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `{% load static %}` также и в `base.html`. А также откройте страницу в браузере и через `CTRL`+`U` проверьте, нет ли блока целиком, или же блок есть, но `href` пуст

Comment: Добавил, без результата. Он его даже не рендерит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в первой строке base.html
У вас:

```
{% extend "index.html" %}
```

Нужно:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
```

[[Доки по Jinja]](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/)

И убедитесь, что вы рендерите `base.html`, а не `index.html`

Comment: Поменял на {% extends "index.html" %}
Ребутнул сервер - без результатов
Я использую стандартный шаблонизатор без Jinja

Comment: @ЕвгенийСафронов какую ошибку выдаёт Django?

Comment: Нет ошибок, все норм открывается но содержимое блока( {% block style %}{% endblock style %}) не прописывается

Comment: @ЕвгенийСафронов вы какой файл рендерите в Django?

Comment: return render(request, "index.html", context=data)

Comment: @ЕвгенийСафронов рендерить нужно тот файл, который находится в самом конце цепочки. В вашем случае - `base.html`.

Comment: Да, в точку!Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ЕвгенийСафронов если ответ решает вашу проблему, вы можете поставить галочку возле него

Answer (score 0):

Рендерил через return render(request, "index.html", context=data) 
Нужно return render(request, "base.html", context=data)